# How to indicate changed files from TortoiseSVN within Visual Studio 2019

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2019, tortoisesvn

I have just moved from NetBeans to Visual Studio 2019. We are maintaining a legacy code, with little changes all over. We use TortoiseSVN for code management. Now I really miss the NetBeans ability to see at once what I have changed and where, marked by a red blob you can click on.

I have added TortoiseSVN diff to the Tools menu as shown here:

https://tortoisesvn.net/visualstudio.html

which is a great help. But is there a way to make VS show that red blob?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the page you linked to

> ... there are Subversion plugins for Visual Studio like AnkhSVN or VisualSVN, with the latter already using TortoiseSVN for many of its UI...

and at least VisualSVN have [Live Status](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/features/#live-status) to show changes inside WC directly in Studio interface